# Bash addition before multiplication (precedence in expression using parenthesis)

Tags: bash, expression, parentheses, operator-precedence

I'm trying to sum 1 to a variable before multiplying the result
In Java it's something like

```
int upperBound = (curBatch + 1) * elePerBatch;
```

I've tried the following

```
upperBound=$(($curBatch + 1 * $elePerBatch))
upperBound=$((($curBatch + 1) * $elePerBatch))
upperBound=$(((($curBatch + 1)) * $elePerBatch))
upperBound=$(($(($curBatch + 1)) * $elePerBatch))
```

Nothing works, and I get this kind of error

> 0 + 1 * : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* ")

I've seen this error in other questions, but I found no solution to my problem.

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer, not an edit to the problem. Answering your own question is not only allowed, but encouraged.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's better than deleting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out elePerBatch was not initialized.

I couldn't figure out what the error meant, otherwise I would have noticed it.

This works

```
upperBound=$(($(($curBatch + 1)) * $elePerBatch))
```

Comment: This actually provides a good argument for using the dollar sign with variables in a arithmetic expression. The perfectly legal `upperBound=$(( (curBatch + 1) * elePerBatch ))` (note that you don't need to nest arithmetic expressions as shown in the answer) would not have thrown a syntax error; the undefined variable `elePerBatch` would have simply evaluated to zero.